# .OrderBy() Not sorting on the column specified

Tags: c#

Data model:

```
public class man
{
    ...
    public double age { set; get; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ManByage()
{
    ...
    var m = _context.Man.FromSqlRaw("sp_GetMen").ToList();
    m.OrderBy(a => a.age).ToList();
    return Ok(m);
}
```

Result is not sorted by `Age`. Don't see any problem, and all other posts are doing the same.

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linq doesnt sort in place, it returns a sorted list. you need

```
 var msorted = m.OrderBy( a=>a.age ).ToList();
 return Ok(msorted);
```